# RStudio, Rstudio.cloud Errors reading shapefiles

Tags: r, rstudio, shapefile

I've loaded multiple packages / tried numerous methods to read a .shp. None of the methods work and I'm unable to decipher google related suggestions. Running the code in R, the system freezes and the same code in RStudio.cloud only returns various error messages. A list of the packages and code are below. Ultimately, I'm trying to create maps, join with another file and produce a table of the results. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(sf)

require(sf)
area <- read_sf(dsn = ".", layer = "2020ATLclip")

require(rgdal)
shape <- readOGR(dsn= ".", layer = "2020ATLclip.shp")

shape <- readOGR(dsn= ".", layer = "tl_2021_13_concity.shp")

library(raster)

l = readShapePoly("2020ATLclip.shp")
l = readShapePoly("tl_2021_13_concity.shp")

atl.poly <- readOGR("./data", layer = "tl_2021-13_concity.shp")


Cannot open layer 2020ATLclip
Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  : 
  Opening layer failed.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Unable to open /cloud/project/2020ATLclip.shx or /cloud/project/2020ATLclip.SHX. Set SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX config option to YES to restore or create it. (GDAL error 4) 
2: Failed to open file /cloud/project/2020ATLclip.shp.  It may be corrupt or read-only file accessed in update mode. (GDAL error 4) 
>

Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer


 l = readShapePoly("2020ATLclip.shp")
Error in getinfo.shape(filen) : Error opening SHP file
In addition: Warning message:
readShapePoly is deprecated; use rgdal::readOGR or sf::st_read 

> l = readShapePoly("tl_2021_13_concity.shp")
Error in getinfo.shape(filen) : Error opening SHP file
In addition: Warning message:
readShapePoly is deprecated; use rgdal::readOGR or sf::st_read
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For both `readOGR` (from the rgdal package) and `st_read` (from the newer sf package), when importing a shapefile the `dsn=` parameter must point to the shp file - with extension *.shp. The `layer=`  parameter is unnecessary with shapefiles. And you **must also have the other components** of the shapefile format in the same directory: the *.shx, *.dbf, and *.prj.  Assuming you have these files in the current working directory, then...

If you insist on using the rgdal library:

```
library(rgdal)
shape <- readOGR(dsn= "2020ATLclip.shp")
# returns an object of class Spatial*DataFrame from sp
```

Preferably you should switch to sf, then

```
library(sf)
shape <- st_read(dsn = "2020ATLclip.shp")
# returns an object of class sf
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I really do appreciate the assistance, it has helped me tremendously. Hopefully (with a little more 
 trial and error), I will be able to keep things moving! With kind regards.